# Porque não consigo visualizar o Javac?

Tags: java

Colegas.

Baixei o sdk jre1.8.0_73, porém não consigo ver o javac dentro da pasta bin. Já criei a variável de ambiente e mesmo assim nada. Essa versão não existe mais o javac?

Comment: Estou com o mesmo jdk e está normal. Tente reinstalar.

Comment: *Baixei o sdk jre1.8.0_73*: tem certeza que é o JDK e não apenas a JRE? Apesar de parecida em alguns pontos, a estrutura de diretórios e arquivos é bem diferente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se na própria pergunta você diz que o nome é JRE então não é o JDK.

Portanto...

- Ou você não instalou o JDK (desenvolvimento) e sim o JRE (execução), que não tem o `javac`
- Ou você instalou o JDK, mas como ele também vem com o JRE dentro dele, você está simplesmente olhando para o diretório errado. Neste caso procure pela pasta `bin` imediatamente dentro do JDK e não em outros diretórios.